# Отслеживание памяти по всем объектам при отладке

Tags: c#, memory, outofmemoryerror

Есть цикл, где каждая итерация независима от другой. При каждой итерации один и тот же массив инициализируется новыми данными. В итоге на 5 итерации кончается память и на моменте добавления в массив нового элемента выскакивает `OutOfMemory`.
Я прописал в конфиг

```
<runtime>
<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
</runtime>
```

Но всё равно. Уже в конце итерации я приравниваю ко всем массивам `null` и вызываю сборщик мусора

```
GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration);
```

Но ничего не помогает. Как можно отследить, куда девается память? Потому что на следующей итерации нам вообще ненужна память, которая выделялась на предыдущей. Но, если смотреть через `Диспетчер задач`, то там после каждой итерации память выделяется всё больше и больше, не чистится. Можете подсказать пожалуйста, где что посмотреть или сделать?

Comment: Использовть профайлер памяти, например [dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/)

Comment: @tym32167 почитаю про него, спасибо) Кстати, отказался я полностью от ООП, сделал все свои расчеты с переменными, без объектов и красоты, в итоге производительность увеличилась в тысячи раз)

Comment: Сборщик мусора удаляет мусор при удобном случае => если вы дальше по коду не используете данные объекты, то это не гарантирует, что сборщик сию же секунду все уберет.

Comment: @Fresto если ваша программа хорошо работает без ООП и продолжает оставаться понятной\тестируемой\расширяемой, то значит ООП там было и не нужно :) Кстати, я указал на dotMemory так как его использую, но он платный. Бесплатных альтернатив я не гуглил, но они наверняка где то есть

Comment: @tym32167 хорошо, там есть пробное время, посмотрим, спасибо)

Comment: @Fresto если сразу понять, как найти проблемы с памятью не получится, обратите внимание на [документацию](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/documentation/) и даже бесплатную [книгу](https://leanpub.com/detectingandsolvingmemoryproblemsinnet/)